# Can't connect to Solana devnet using Solana-Web3.js

Tags: web3.js

Just start learning the demo and trying to connect to devnet to get the balance of the account.

```
import { Connection, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
const publicKey = new PublicKey("83astBRguLMdt2h5U1Tpdq5tjFoJ6noeGwaY3mDLVcri");
const balanceInLamports = await connection.getBalance(publicKey);
const balanceInSOL = balanceInLamports / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;
console.log(`✅ Finished! The balance for the wallet at address ${publicKey} is ${balanceInSOL}!`);
```

then I got the error
[image]

but it works well when I using JSON-RPC method.
[image]

I found a similar question in [stakoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71763955/cant-connect-to-solana-devnet-testnet), but didn't solve this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I ran your exact code with version 1.87.6 of web3.js and it worked beautifully. Maybe try updating to a newer version of the library?